# Windows Phone 7, Steganography and MediaLibrary.SavePicture

Tags: windows-phone-7, metadata, steganography

I am working with MediaLibrary on WP7 and I am doing steganography on BitmapImage (WriteableBitmap) which works fine (using this approach: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4877/Steganography-Hiding-messages-in-the-Noise-of-a-Pi)

Now the problem occurs when I call MediaLibrary.SavePicture method to save my bitmap to the phone. When I load this saved bitmap again from the phone, I can see that the pixels of the bitmap are shifted and my steganography data is lost.
Is there a way to avoid this behavior during the save method?

Better yet, is there a way to attach some metadata to my bitmaps that would be persisted with the bitmap?

Thanks a lot!
Leo

Comment: Can you show the line of code you use to save the bitmap? How do you produce the stream/byte array you pass in?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be caused by the fact that `MediaLibrary.SavePicture` saves the stream as a JPEG whereas your bytestream represents an uncompressed bitmap. Since JPEG is a lossy compression format, your data might be thrown away and so your hidden byte stream becomes corrupt. I'm not familiar with steganography but, if possible, you could try creating a blank JPEG image and writing your data to that. This way, your image format remains the same. You could try using [Extensions.SaveJpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28VS.92%29.aspx) with a `quality` value of `100`, writing the data to that and then saving it to the MediaLibrary.